# Android Marker View How to Show circle in the graph

Tags: java, android, xml

I Have implemented line graph like this,

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_graph_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_138sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_day_percentage">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                    android:id="@+id/chart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

I want that a circle should shown like this where this vertical line is intersecting the graph like this
[image]

But right now i am not able to get this circle.. how can i render the circle where vertical line is intersecting with graph

[image]

this is the custom marker view i am using

```
public class MfMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    private final TextView tvTitle;
    private final TextView tvSubTitle;
    private final ImageView ivMiddle;
    private final ImageView ivLeft;
    private final ImageView ivRight;
    private final List<NavHistory> navHistoryList;

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    public MfMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource, List<NavHistory> navHistoryList) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        tvTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvSubTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvSubTitle);
        ivMiddle = findViewById(R.id.iv_middle);
        ivLeft = findViewById(R.id.iv_left);
        ivRight = findViewById(R.id.iv_right);
        this.navHistoryList = navHistoryList;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        try {
            String value;
            if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {
                CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;
                value = String.valueOf(ce.getHigh());
            } else {
                value = String.valueOf(e.getY());
            }

            if (e.getX() < 200) {
                ivLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ivMiddle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (e.getX() > 200 && e.getX() < 900) {
                ivLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivMiddle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ivRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                ivLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivMiddle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            String navDate = getDateFromNav(value);
            if (!navDate.isEmpty()) {
                String formattedDate = DateTimeUtils.getFormattedDate(navDate);
                String displayText = Constants.RUPEES + " " + value;
                tvTitle.setText(displayText);
                tvSubTitle.setText("NAV as on " + formattedDate);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

    @Override
    public MPPointF getOffset() {
        return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2f), -500);
    }

    private String getDateFromNav(String navRate) {
        String navDate = "";
        try {
            if (navHistoryList != null) {
                for (NavHistory navHistory : navHistoryList) {
                    if (decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(navHistory.getNav()))).equals(navRate)) {
                        navDate = navHistory.getNavDate();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return navDate;
    }

}
```